# Android java make call to url

Tags: java, android

I want to simulate opening a url (ie [www.website.com/page.php?data=something](http://www.website.com/page.php?data=something)), but without actually opening a browser. I don't care if there is a response, so I don't need to handle that.  Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT:
Alright, so I have made *some* progress, but nothing actually working.  So far I have an AsyncTask to run this:

```
{
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/folder/file.php?PAYLOAD=stringOfText");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.connect();
}
```

but nothing happens on the server side.  For comparison, if I go to a browser and type the url in (http://example.com/folder/file.php?PAYLOAD=stringOfText), it responds as intended (that php generates another html file).

I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this at this point. I didn't use a lot of other code in httpUrlConnection because I wasn't using any return information.

Comment: yes, take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: Alright, so I have made *some* progress, but nothing actually working.